# I just got a solution to "Parse file name and path from full path". Can someone please help me understand the code?

Tags: t-sql

I just got an excellent answer to "Parse file name and path from full path" which was given by @AgentSQL.

The answer was simple and effective but I am having trouble understanding it. The code is as follows:

```
DECLARE @full_path VARCHAR(1000)
SET @full_path = '\\SERVER\D$\EXPORTFILES\EXPORT001.csv'

SELECT LEFT(@full_path,LEN(@full_path) - charindex('\',reverse(@full_path),1) + 1) [path], 
       REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@full_path),CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@full_path), 1) - 1)) [file_name]
```

I do understand the functions left, reverse and charindex when used separately, but I would really appreciate if someone can help me understand the code in it's entirety.

Comment: Suggestion: make a copy of the SELECT statement. Remove the outermost "layter" of parentheses, run, see what it does. Copy that, remove the (now) outermost "layter" of parentheses, run, see what that does. Repeat until you've drilled down through all the function calls.

Comment: Philip, I tried to do that but it is failing because the output is going through many layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @full_path VARCHAR(1000)
SET @full_path = '\\abc\files\india\users\dknthasdx\Dropped CUSIPs_12_10_2014.xlsx'
select REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@full_path),CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@full_path), 1) - 1)) [FileName]



--1) REVERSE(@full_path) --Reverses the whole path : xslx.4102_01_21_sPISUC depporD\sznahtnam\sresu\aidni\selif\lns\\

--2) CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@full_path), 1) -- Returns 31 in this case : The index  first occurence in REVERSE PATH OF /

--3) LEFT(REVERSE(@full_path),CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@full_path), 1) - 1) -- return the expression till first occurence of /

--4) REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@full_path),CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@full_path), 1) - 1)) [FileName] -- reverse the String again (reversed earlier) to get the file name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  --two additional variants  
DECLARE @full_path VARCHAR(1000)
    SET @full_path = '\\SERVER\D$\EXPORTFILES\EXPORT001.csv'
    --1 variant
    SELECT  REPLACE(@full_path,RIGHT(@full_path, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@full_path)) - 1), '') [path] ,
            RIGHT(@full_path, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@full_path)) - 1) [file_name]  

    --2 variant
    SELECT  LEFT(@full_path,(LEN(@full_path) - CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@full_path)) + 1)) [path] ,
            RIGHT(@full_path, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@full_path)) - 1) [file_name]
```